# Factors of $x^3+ 5x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

As $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=f(5)$, where $0,1,2,3,4,5$ are under mod $6$, can we write $x^3+5=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$?

I am extremely sorry for the typo.

Comment: If $f(x) = x^3 + 5$, $f(0) \not\equiv f(1) \pmod 6$.

Comment: How ? both f(0) = f(1) = 0 ?

Comment: No they aren't; $f(0) = 0^3 + 5 = 0 + 5 = 5$ and $f(1) = 1^3 + 5 = 1 + 5 = 6$.

Comment: $f(0)$ is $-1$ whereas $f(1)$ is $0$, so surely they are not equal, no? (Edit: Albanese beat me to it)

Comment: But if you want a low degree polynomial with a lot of modular zeros, take a look at
$$f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\in\Bbb{Z}_{24}[x].$$ You have $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in\Bbb{Z}_{24}$.

Comment: I am sorry the polynomial is $x^3+5x. please tell if now my factorisation is correct ?

Comment: you have two polynomials $x^3+5$ and $x^3+5x$.. which one are you calling as $f(x)$?

Comment: I am sorry i didn't mean $x^3$+5 rather i was asking about $x^3$+5x .. it was a typing error.

Comment: No. Your factorization is incorrect. The product is of degree 5, so it cannot be equal to a cubic.

Comment: I know this degree mismatch and that is why i am confused. I can see all of (x-1),(x-2),(x-3),(x-4),(x-5) are factors of $x^3$+5x then why don't they show up in the factorization ?

Comment: Please check if my construction of nil potent elements and zero divisors are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little chance of getting unique factorization when your ring has zero divisors. For example modulo four you have
$$
x^2\equiv x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2).
$$
The same happens here. Where it breaks down is when you factor out one zero, the remaining factor has a much smaller set of zeros than what you might expect. For example
$$x^3+5x=x(x^2+5),$$
but the only zeros of $x^2+5$ are $\pm1$. $x=3$ is not a zero of either factor, but it is a zero of the product.

Answer (score 1):

Your decomposition is certainly wrong (look at the degree!), but you can decompose the polynomial as follows:
$$x^3+5x = x(x^2+5)=x(x^2-1)=x(x+1)(x-1)$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_6[x]$.